# Нужна помощь в составлении SQL запроса

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Помогите составить запрос.
Есть таблица, в которой хранится информация о входе/выходе сотрудников.
Необходимо получить данные о **первом** входе и **последнем** выходе каждого сотрудника за каждый день, исключив промежуточные данные.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полная структура таблицы
[image: Полная структура таблицы]

В конечном итоге планируется выводить данные в подобном формате в WPF приложении.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user,DATE(datetime) ORDER BY datetime ASC/DESC) = 1`